# How to insert image at end of Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am trying to insert an image into a Word document but it is always inserted at the start of the document. I want to insert that image at a specific position. Is there any way to insert the image at a specific position in the document?

This is my code

```
range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imgloc, ref oTrue, ref oFalse,Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please pay more attention to the composition of your question next time. Things like capitalization, punctuation and using proper code formatting matter.

Comment: really at the end of your document? is so, instead of your last `Type.Missing` parameter you need to use reference to the last paragraph of the document. You could use reference to `End of document bookmark`. In VBA this parameter would be as follows: `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant answer but it has worked for me.

//add a space to force the cursor to a new line in the document

//sometimes the cursor is left at the end of a text string

`mydocument.Content.Text += " ";'

//set the range to the entire contents of the document

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = mydocument.Content;'

//collapse the entire range

`rng.Collapse(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);'

//add the image. make sure you have the collapsed range as the last parameter
                    'mydocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(objRecTimeLineEvent.FilePath, false, true,rng);'

Comment: Check this [Markdown Editing Help - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)